# Little Pin Icon on Java Class - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, symbols

I don't know what I did... But that's the only file that have like a **Pin Icon**. What does it mean, and how can I **remove** it? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That `java` file class has a Pin because that class is a `final class`

May be you have declared that class as a `final class` :)

To learn more about: [Android studio symbols](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html)

Answer (score 6):

> what is that ?

It is because you have declared that class as **final class** due to that it is showing that pin icon.

> How to remove pin icon ?

If you **remove final keyword** than that icon will be removed.

Check out description of [symbols](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/symbols.html) used in android studio

[image]