# A white symbol on a java class in Android Studio 3.5.3

Tags: android-studio

There is a weird white symbol (Like hammer) in one of my `FirestoreStaticHelper.java`. Like this (top of **C**)

[image: weird_white_symbol]

[image: weird_white_symbol_in_top]

FirestoreStaticHelper class only have static methods and private constructor. I have other similar classes like this. but only this class is showing this symbol.

1. What is this symbol?
2. How to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46417873)

Your `FirestoreStaticHelper` class is a final class. That's why there is a pin in that icon. If you want to remove it you have to remove `final` keyword from the class